# MSXML : Invalid Class String

Tags: xml, xslt, vb6, macros, msxml

I have installed in my pc
MSXML 2.6
MSXML 3.0
MSXML 4.0
MSXML 6.0

when i try to parse my XSL in execution time i have the error Invalid Class String
these is the code

```
Public Sub PreviewDOCUMENT()
    Dim ObjXMLTransformDoc
    Dim ObjXMLTransformStyle
    Dim ObjXMLDoc
    Dim ObjXMLStyle
    Dim ObjXsltSettings
    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER

    If mResultPath <> "" Then

        Set ObjXMLTransformDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
        ObjXMLTransformDoc.Load (mResultPath & MyDocument.DOC_TYPE & "_XML_TO_XSL.xml")

        Set ObjXMLTransformStyle = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
        ObjXMLTransformStyle.Load ActiveWorkbook.path & "\RESULT\form_generation.xsl"

        ObjXMLTransformStyle.setProperty "AllowXsltScript", True

        Set ObjXMLStyle = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")
        ObjXMLTransformDoc.transformNodetoObject ObjXMLTransformStyle, ObjXMLStyle

        KillFile mResultPath & MyDocument.DOC_TYPE & "_DOCUMENT_STYLE.xsl"
        DoEvents
        AppendToTextFile mResultPath & MyDocument.DOC_TYPE & "_DOCUMENT_STYLE.xsl", ObjXMLStyle.XML


        Dim mSE As New CShellExecute
        mSE.LaunchDocument 0, mResultPath & MyDocument.DOC_TYPE & "_XML_TO_XML.xml", ActiveWorkbook.path & "\RESULT\", sesSW_SHOWDEFAULT
    Else
        MsgBox "Create documents first!"
    End If
Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLER:
  MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to msxml4 in your project? Apart from that I would use msxml6 as this is part of Windows now and needs no separate deployment.

Comment: When i use MSXML 6.0 i have the error: Javascript is not a scripting language.

Comment: That is completely baffling ;-). On what line do you get the VB6 error about the invalid class string?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember the default loading is asynchronous so for your sequence of code to make sense you need to add `ObjXMLTransformDoc.async = False` before the `ObjXMLTransformDoc.Load` load call and `ObjXMLTransformStyle.async = False` before the `ObjXMLTransformStyle.Load` call.
Whether the error message you get is related to that I am not sure however. Can you tell us the exact statement or line you get that error for?

Comment: the line is:ObjXMLTransformDoc.transformNodetoObject ObjXMLTransformStyle, ObjXMLStyle